# Lambda for nested arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, .net-4.0, lambda

I have a List of custom objects:

```
List<SomeObject> someobjects = getAllSomeObjects();
List<SomeObject> someobjectsfiltered = new List<SomeObject>();

class SomeObject
{
  List <AnotherList>
}

class AnotherList
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public Categories category {get;set;}
}
```

So I'm trying to get All AnotherList items of a specific type using Lambda

```
someobjectsfiltered = someobjects.SelectMany(s => s.AnotherList.FindAll(a => a.category == SomeCategory));
```

But I get the

> Can not implicitly convert type
>   IEnumerable to Generic.List

error

Any idea how to solve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to throw a `ToList()` on the end or change the type of the result to `IEnumerable<SomeObject>` because, as the error says, you can't assign an `IEnumerable<T>` to a variable of type `List<T>`.

```
someobjectsfiltered = someobjects.SelectMany(s => s.AnotherList.FindAll(a => a.category == SomeCategory))
                                 .ToList();
```

**Edit based on comments**

If what you want is the `SomeObjects` that have a list containing an item that matches the category you can do that using.

```
someobjectsfiltered = someobjects.Where( s => s.AnotherList.Any( a => a.category == SomeCategory ))
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: @adam-rackis Thank you very much that worked fine, out of interest, can I use FindAll().FindAll() here instead of SelectMany().FindAll()?

Comment: @Maya - I don't think so.  SelectMany does a projection and concatenation while FindAll does a filter.  It would be like trying to replace a `select` with a `where` clause.

Comment: Apologies @tvanfosson , I have tested the ToList() solution it worked fine if that someobjectsfiltered was a type of AnotherList, but I tested it against my original code above where someobjectsfiltered is a List of SomeObject and that gave an error can not convert List<AnotherList> to List<SomeObject>. I probably should've tested it probably against the exact code above before commenting here.

Comment: @Maya - I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  I thought you were trying to get the AnotherList objects with the matching categories.  Are you trying to get the SomeObjects whose lists contain an item with the matching category?  That would be different.  I'll add that to my answer.  If it really is the former, then the filtered list must be of type `List<AnotherList>` (which is a horribly misleading class name, by the way).

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I was trying to do (your initial answer although helped me solving another issue). Now all is working fine, I apologise for the misleading names in the example, I didn't do a good job masking the actual sensitive names quickly before I posted, many thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

@tvanfosson @Maya Not sure how "Any" would work here since it will come back with true all the time causing the whole AnotherList (the inner list) to be selected back, if that "Category" type exist once in the inner list then all of its contents will be selected including those with the unwanted Category types.

Comment: That's true, I got it answered here though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130152/lambda-with-nested-classes

Answer (score 1):

`SelectMany` returns `IEnumerable<T>` - you can convert that to a `List<T>` by simply adding a call to `ToList()` onto the end.

```
someobjectsfiltered = someobjects.SelectMany(s => s.AnotherList.FindAll(a => a.category == SomeCategory)).ToList();
```