# Lambda with nested classes

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, lambda, nested-class

I have posted this question a while ago but got a partial answer to my issue, so I thought I post more explanation hoping to get a more accurate answer. I have 2 classes:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Cars> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public CarTypes CarType { get; set; }
    public enum CarTypes
    {
        Van,
        SmallCar
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get only All employees that have vans allocated to ignoring those with SmallCars using Lambda, I tried this line:

```
List<Employee> EmployeesWithVans = AllEmployees.Where(emps => emps.Car.Any(cartype => cartype.CarType == Car.CarTypes.Van)).ToList();
```

But this gets all employees if at least one van is allocated to an Employee (`.Any`) if I try (`.All`) it will bring back nothing as not all employees has Van.

Any idea if this can be achieved using nested Lambda?

Thanks.

Edit:

```
Employee Mark = new Employee();
Mark.Cars.Add(new Car() { CarType = Car.CarTypes.Van, CarID = 12 });
Mark.Cars.Add(new Car() { CarType = Car.CarTypes.Van, CarID = 13 });
Mark.Cars.Add(new Car() { CarType = Car.CarTypes.SmallCar, CarID = 14 });

Employee Lisa = new Employee();
Lisa.Cars.Add(new Car() { CarType = Car.CarTypes.Van, CarID = 15 });
Lisa.Cars.Add(new Car() { CarType = Car.CarTypes.SmallCar, CarID = 16 });
Lisa.Cars.Add(new Car() { CarType = Car.CarTypes.SmallCar, CarID = 17 });

    List<Employee> EmployeesWithVans should contain:

    Employee FilteredMark contains:
    Mark.Cars.Add(new Car() { CarType = Car.CarTypes.Van, CarID = 12 });
    Mark.Cars.Add(new Car() { CarType = Car.CarTypes.Van, CarID = 13 });

    Employee FilteredLisa contains:
    Mark.Cars.Add(new Car() { CarType = Car.CarTypes.Van, CarID = 15 });
```

Comment: Looks like she wants Employees who dosen't also have a small car...

Comment: you haven't mentioned `carID` etc.. however i have edited my answer as per your Update..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Instead:

```
List<Employee> Temp = AllEmployees.Where(emps => emps.Cars.Any(cartype => cartype.CarType == Cars.CarTypes.Van)).ToList();

List<Employee> EmployeesWithVans = (from item in Temp
           select new Employee{ 
                                     Name = item.Name, 
                                     Cars = (item.Cars.Where( car => car.CarType == Cars.CarTypes.Van)).ToList()
                               }).ToList();
```

---

This is what i tried (In LINQPAD):

```
void Main()
{
    List<Employee> AllEmployees = new List<Employee>();

    List<Cars> lcars1 = new List<Cars>();
    Cars car1 = new Cars();
    car1.CarType = Cars.CarTypes.Van;
    lcars1.Add(car1);lcars1.Add(car1);

    Cars car2 = new Cars();
    car2.CarType = Cars.CarTypes.SmallCar;
    lcars1.Add(car2);

    List<Cars> lcars2 = new List<Cars>();
    lcars2.Add(car1);lcars2.Add(car2);lcars2.Add(car2);

    AllEmployees.Add(new Employee(){ Name="emp1", Cars = lcars1});
    AllEmployees.Add(new Employee(){ Name="emp2", Cars = lcars2});
    AllEmployees.Add(new Employee(){ Name="emp3", Cars = lcars1 });
    AllEmployees.Add(new Employee(){ Name="emp4", Cars = lcars2});

    List<Employee> Temp = AllEmployees.Where(emps => emps.Cars.Any(cartype => cartype.CarType == Cars.CarTypes.Van)).ToList();

    List<Employee> EmployeesWithVans = (from item in Temp
            select new Employee{ 
                                        Name = item.Name, 
                                        Cars = (item.Cars.Where( car => car.CarType == Cars.CarTypes.Van)).ToList()
                                }).ToList();

    EmployeesWithVans.Dump();
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this would return all employees who **do not** have a van - I don't think that's what OP wants

Comment: yeah i was just trying it and found that.. have changed my code.. Thanx for pointing that out

Comment: ahhh you are a star! Many thanks you deserve a big +1, sorry for the CarID confusion I just needed to add some object identification.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? (all employees with at least one van, but no smallcar)

```
var EmployeesWithVans = AllEmployees
                        .Where(emps => emps.Cars.Any(cartype => cartype.CarType == Cars.CarTypes.Van)
                                       && !emps.Cars.Any(cartype => cartype.CarType == Cars.CarTypes.SmallCar))
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is correct, it adds an `Employee` to the return sequence if it is assigned a van. I'm not quite sure where the question lies, do you think your query will return nothing as not all employees have a van? If yes, this would be the implementation of a `Where` operator:

```
foreach(var elem in input)
{
  if (predicate(elem))
    yield return elem;
}
```

The predicate will be applied to all elements in your sequence, if the element fulfills it, it will be returned as part of the sequence.

Comment: @BrokenGlass @Femaref @Shekhar_Pro I have added example to the question, does it make sense, an output of a new Employee list with employee items containing cars of type van only added?